# Split pandas dataframe string into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of text strings which essentially represents one or many journeys per row. I'm trying to split the legs of the journey so I can see them individually. The example input dataframe looks as follows:

UPDATED:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame([{'var1':'A/A1', 'var2':'x/y/z', 'var3':'abc1'}, 
                         {'var1':'B', 'var2':'xx/yy', 'var3':'abc2'}, 
                         {'var1':'c', 'var2':'zz', 'var3':'abcd'}])

   var1 var2    var3
0  A/A1 x/y/z   abc1
1   B   xx/yy   abc2
2   c   zz      abcd
```

The output I'm trying to get should look as follows. So for the first example, the journey legs are `A to A1 then A1 to x then x to y and then y to z`. If there is also a way to add an additional column indicating the journey leg number (1,2,3 etc.) that'll be very helpful. `var3` has no importance here, but I've just included it to show that there are other columns which get repeated when the rows are split.

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'A', 'var2': 'A1', 'var3':'abc1'}, 
                          {'var1': 'A1', 'var2': 'x', 'var3':'abc1'},
                          {'var1': 'x', 'var2': 'y', 'var3':'abc1'},
                          {'var1': 'y', 'var2': 'z', 'var3':'abc1'},
                          {'var1': 'B', 'var2': 'xx', 'var3':'abc2'},
                          {'var1': 'xx', 'var2': 'yy', 'var3':'abc2'},
                          {'var1': 'c', 'var2': 'zz', 'var3':'abcd'}])

  var1 var2 var3
0   A   A1  abc1
1   A1  x   abc1
2   x   y   abc1
3   y   z   abc1
4   B   xx  abc2
5   xx  yy  abc2
6   c   zz  abcd
```

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with `explode`

```
df=df_input.assign(var2=df_input.var2.str.split('/')).explode('var2')
  var1 var2  var3
0    A    x  abc1
0    A    y  abc1
0    A    z  abc1
1    B   xx  abc2
1    B   yy  abc2
2    c   zz  abcd
```

Then `groupby` + `shift`

```
df.var1=df.groupby(level=0).var2.shift().fillna(df.var1)
df
  var1 var2  var3
0    A    x  abc1
0    x    y  abc1
0    y    z  abc1
1    B   xx  abc2
1   xx   yy  abc2
2    c   zz  abcd
```

Comment: Thanks! Can this also work in the scenario when I have multiple enteries in `var1` column? I've updated the original question to show the example.

Comment: I tried repeating the code on both columns but it doesn't work that way. Not sure how to handle this scenario when there are multiple `/` separated entries in both columns

Answer (score 4):

## Solution

Try this.

`EDIT`: Made a change based on the suggestion from [@Ben.T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9274732/ben-t?tab=profile).

```py
df = pd.concat([df.rename(columns={'var2': 'var2old'}), 
                df.var2.str.split('/').explode()], 
               axis=1, join='outer')
## CREDIT: @Ben.T
df['var1'] = df['var1'].where(df['var1'].ne(df['var1'].shift()), df['var2'].shift())
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```sh
  var1 var2old  var3 var2
0    A   x/y/z  abc1    x
0    x   x/y/z  abc1    y
0    y   x/y/z  abc1    z
1    B   xx/yy  abc2   xx
1   xx   xx/yy  abc2   yy
2    c      zz  abcd   zz
```

### Dummy Data

The data originally posted by the OP (*Original Poster* of the question).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'var1':'A', 'var2':'x/y/z', 'var3':'abc1'}, 
                   {'var1':'B', 'var2':'xx/yy', 'var3':'abc2'}, 
                   {'var1':'c', 'var2':'zz', 'var3':'abcd'}])
```

Comment: @Ben.T Thank you. Good catch! I will get back with the solution later.

Comment: @Ben.T added the suggested solution to make the answer complete. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! Can this also work in the scenario when I have multiple enteries in `var1` column? I've updated the original question to show the example.

Comment: It will not work as it is, since your updated data follows a different logic. However, you can try something similar and flatten column-var1 first and then apply this solution on it. I would suggest that you create a new question with your updated data and leave a reference to that here. The solutions posted here work for what you had asked initially. Now, when you change your question, these solutions APPEAR to be not correct. So, I request you to not drop (at least) your original data from the question. Thank you.

Comment: Makes sense, will do that. Thanks!