# Split pandas dataframe column string with multiple values into separate rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of text strings which essentially represents one or many journeys per row. I'm trying to split the legs of the journey so I can see them individually. The example input dataframe looks as follows:

```
df_input = pd.DataFrame([{'var1':'A/A1', 'var2':'x/y/z', 'var3':'abc1'}, 
                         {'var1':'B', 'var2':'xx/yy', 'var3':'abc2'}, 
                         {'var1':'c', 'var2':'zz', 'var3':'abcd'}])

   var1 var2    var3
0  A/A1 x/y/z   abc1
1   B   xx/yy   abc2
2   c   zz      abcd
```

The output I'm trying to get should look as follows. So for the first example, the journey legs are `A to A1 then A1 to x then x to y and then y to z`. If there is also a way to add an additional column indicating the journey leg number (1,2,3 etc.) that'll be very helpful. `var3` has no importance here, but I've just included it to show that there are other columns which get repeated when the rows are split.

```
df_output = pd.DataFrame([{'var1': 'A', 'var2': 'A1', 'var3':'abc1'}, 
                          {'var1': 'A1', 'var2': 'x', 'var3':'abc1'},
                          {'var1': 'x', 'var2': 'y', 'var3':'abc1'},
                          {'var1': 'y', 'var2': 'z', 'var3':'abc1'},
                          {'var1': 'B', 'var2': 'xx', 'var3':'abc2'},
                          {'var1': 'xx', 'var2': 'yy', 'var3':'abc2'},
                          {'var1': 'c', 'var2': 'zz', 'var3':'abcd'}])

  var1 var2 var3
0   A   A1  abc1
1   A1  x   abc1
2   x   y   abc1
3   y   z   abc1
4   B   xx  abc2
5   xx  yy  abc2
6   c   zz  abcd
```

Can someone please help? I posted a similar (simpler) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62825570/6900402) earlier, but reposting since the complexity has increased and the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62825766/6900402) doesn't work for a scenario where both `var1` and `var2` have multiple entries separated by a `/`.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way from `join` + `explode` then `shift`

```
df_input['New']=df_input[['var1','var2']].agg('/'.join,1).str.split('/')
df=df_input.explode('New')
df['New2']=df.groupby(level=0).New.shift(-1)
df=df.dropna(subset=['New2'],axis=0)
df
   var1   var2  var3 New New2
0  A/A1  x/y/z  abc1   A   A1
0  A/A1  x/y/z  abc1  A1    x
0  A/A1  x/y/z  abc1   x    y
0  A/A1  x/y/z  abc1   y    z
1     B  xx/yy  abc2   B   xx
1     B  xx/yy  abc2  xx   yy
2     c     zz  abcd   c   zz
```

Comment: Is it also possible to assign an additional column to represent the journey leg number in the order they appear i.e. `A to A1` = 1, `A1 to x` = 2..? I think they are always ordered in the output dataframe, so if adding that order # column isn't easy, that's fine. I'll be importing the dataset into SQL, so I guess I can always use `partition by var1 order by row_number()` to assign an order # that way.